# Django ManytoManyField Display User Profile

Tags: django

I got stuck when trying to display User Name as Manytomanyfield in django template, but always display with

```
<QuerySet [<Profile: User 1>]>
```

how can i display it without queryset bla bla bla... just User 1 (First Name or Last Name or Full Name)

```
class Referral(models.Model):
    ref = models.ManyToManyField(Profile, related_name='ref')
    profile = models.ForeignKey(Profile, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.ref)
```

```
{% for tree in tree %}
<section>
<span class="diagram-icon"></span>
<span class=diagram-label>{{ tree.ref.all }}</span>
</section>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using

```
<span class=diagram-label>{{ tree.ref.all.0.firstName }}</span>
```

If you want all users, you can do:

```
{% for ref_user in tree.ref.all %}
    {{ ref_user }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: also you can overide your view "get_context_data" method and send already defined object

Comment: There are many more problems, I'll suggest to look at the docs.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print all the usernames of particular referral, you can do it like:

```
{% for r in referral.ref.all %}
        {{ r.username}}
{% endfor %}
```